# Can you mix shared pointers with non-pointer data members?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Take the following example:

```
class BookManager
   {
   ...
   };

class Book
   {
   public:
      void setBookManager(BookManager *bookManager) {m_bookManager = bookManager;}
   private:
      BookManager *m_bookManager;
   };
```

Since the caller is typically not interested in keeping a BookManager for a Book if the Book is deleted, and since multiple Books can share a BookManager, I make the pointer to BookManager, a shared pointer, like this:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<BookManager> BookManagerPtr;

class Book
   {
   public:
      void setBookManager(BookManagerPtr bookManager) {m_bookManager = bookManager;}
   private:
      BookManagerPtr m_bookManager;
   };
```

Problem is that a module in my application has its own BookManager that it wants to give to each of its books, like this:

```
class MyModule
   {
   public:
      Book *createBook()
         {
         Book *newBook = new Book();
         newBook->setBookManager(BookManagerPtr(&m_bookManager));
         }
   private:
      BookManager m_bookManager;
   };
```

Of course this doesn't work because the last deleted book will also delete the BookManager instance, which it shouldn't delete because it's a normal data member of MyModule.

This means that MyModule should also use a shared pointer to BookManager, like this:

```
class MyModule
   {
   public:
      MyModule()
      : m_bookManager(new BookManager())
         {
         }
      Book *createBook()
         {
         Book *newBook = new Book();
         newBook->setBookManager(m_bookManager);
         }
   private:
      BookManagerPtr m_bookManager;
   };
```

Is this the only way to solve this?
Or is there a way to still have normal data members and use shared pointers to it (e.g. by initializing its reference count to 1)?

Comment: Be careful not to use an unnamed shared pointer like you do in the first version of MyModule::createBook(). See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#BestPractices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a copy `BookManagerPtr(new BookMarkManager(m_bookManager))`, make m_bookManager a BookManagerPtr too or make book a template thus allowing it to use BookManager* and shared_ptr.
shared_ptr is about shared ownership, in your example MyModule owns the example and book don't, so it's not compatible with shared_ptr

Answer (score 1):

What about using custom deleter which does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

I know you've accepted an answer, but another approach (if you have boost) could be to use references. By default you can't have a reference member in the `Book` class, however if you wrap it in an optional i.e. `boost::optional<BookManager&>` then you can have a reference, next, in the `setBookManager` method, pass in the reference (or const reference) and assign this to the optional. To use, deref as you would a smart pointer...

Answer (score 0):

The safe way to model non-ownership is with a `weak_ptr` this way the lifetime is still controlled by `MyModule` while still having `Book` reference a `BookManager` and know if the `BookManager` it references is still valid.